# Редирект на страницу просмотра

Tags: .htaccess, веб-сервер, редирект

У меня в корневом каталоге есть папка /special-offers/index.php и папка /popular-directions/index.php. Я где-то видел, что можно просто поместить все индексные файлы страниц в одну папку с названием, например, view, но чтобы при этом в адресной строке все равно отображались правильные адреса - `/special-offers/` или `/popular-directions/`, а не `/view/special-offers.php/`. Как называется эта фича/технология и в каких фреймворках это удобнее всего использовать?

Comment: Знакомимся с [ЧПУ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_URL)

Answer (score 0):

Эта фича называется редирект. Она настраивается в файлах `.htaccess` и не зависит от движков и фреймворков, a выполняется сервером.

Например в вашем случае, редирект может быть таким:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule special-offers/ /view/special-offers/index.php
```

[Подробнее о настройке  .htaccess](http://hosting.nic.ru/support/htaccess.shtml)